# How do I use division to determine whether "$x+4$" is a factor of "$x^3 + 3x^2 -10x -24$"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Didn't learnt this part in class and need help with it for homework. 
It gave me "$x + 4$" and says to determine whether the binomial is a factor of "$ x^3 + 3x^2 -10x - 24$"

Please explain how this can be done. I also have another that I will do on my own when I figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**hint**: There is a theorem about this. It states that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial and if $p(a) = 0$ then $x-a$ is a factor of $p(x)$. Your $p(x) = x^3+3x^2-10x-24$, and $a = -4$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use division, just the factor theorem. This states that the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)$ is $f(a)$. This means if we have $f(a)=0$ then $(x-a)$ is a factor.

Plugging in $-4$ to the expression, we get:
$$\begin{align} (-4)^3 + 3(-4)^2 -10(-4) -24 & = -64 + 48 +40 -24 \\
&= 0 
\end{align} $$
Which means, by the factor theorem above, that $(x+4)$ is a factor.

Answer (score 0):

$x^3 + 3x^2-10x - 24\\
x^3+4x^2 - 4x^2 + 3x^2-10x - 24\\
x^2(x+4)  -x^2 - 4x + 4x -10x - 24\\
x^2(x+4)  -x(x+4) - 6x - 24\\
x^2(x+4)  -x(x+4) - 6(x+4)\\
(x^2-x-6)(x+4) = x^3 + 3x^2 - 10 - 24\\
$

Answer (score 0):

$x^3 + 3x^2 -10x - 24=(x+4)(x^2+ax-6)$

Now you have to determine if such an a exist...

$ax^2+4x^2=3x^2 \iff a=-1$

then check that

$4ax-6x=-10x$ for a=-1

so $ x^3 + 3x^2 -10x - 24=(x+4)(x^2-x-6)$

Answer (score 0):

I couple two theorems into one to answer this sort of question. I call this pair the Factor-Remainder Theorem.

> **Theorem.** Suppose $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Let $d$ be a monic linear polynomial (that is, something of the form $x - c$). Then $P(c)$ is the remainder upon dividing $P$ by $d$. If the remainder is zero, then $d | P$, that is, $d$ is a factor of $P$.

This is how we factor polynomials.